# How to bypass the Internet explorer Open or Save notification bar in Win Server 2012 R2?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I am automating an enterprise application and the limitation is to stick to IE11 for automation. I have a critical situation whenever I try to download a document the IE notification appears asking me to "Do you want to open or Save the document from "website example.com"..

[Screen shot HERE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAxcy.jpg)